What's the maximum number of work nodes adjacent to a path for a given grid size?
Given a square grid of path nodes which must be face adjacent to each other, work nodes which must be face adjacent (not corner adjacent) to a path node and a fully connected path which both starts at a corner and may double back on itself, what is the maximum number of work nodes for a given sized grid?
This question is close, but it includes adjacency to outer cells which are not present here, and it allows for corner adjacency. In addition, it gives no requirement for the path to hit a corner node.

What maximum values do you get for small $n \times n$ grids?
